# Dagger использование Inject

Tags: android, dagger

третий день не могу разобраться с даггером, а именно с использованием Inject.
UseCase класс:

```
 public class UseCase {
    @Inject
    Repo repo;
    
    public void getText() {
        repo.repoText();
    }
}
```

Repo Класс:

```
public class Repo {
    @Inject
    Data data;

    public void repoText(){
        data.getDataText();
    }
}
```

Data класс:

```
public class Data {
  
    public void getDataText(){
        System.out.println("ДАТА ТЕКСТ");
    }
}
```

Модуль:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    @Provides
    UseCase useCase(){
        return new UseCase();
    }

    @Provides
    Repo repo(){
        return new Repo();
    }

    @Provides
    Data providesData(){
        return new Data();
    }
}
```

Компонент:

```
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    UseCase getUseCase();
    void inject(UseCase useCase);
}
```

И реализация:

```
AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.create();
    UseCase useCase = appComponent.getUseCase();
    appComponent.inject(useCase);
    useCase.getText();
```

Проблема в том, что не создается класс Data который реализуется в классе Repo. Что я делаю не так? Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том что dagger не может инжектит data класс в repo, так как вы не прописали inject метод в AppComponent.
Лучше передайте data класс в конструктор repo. Тогда проблем не возникнет

```
public class Repo {
    Data data;

    public Repo(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void repoText() {
        data.getDataText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но бывают случаи, когда мне не нужно передавать класс в конструктор, а он создается внутри класса, как тогда мой пример реализовать с помощью даггера? А именно: "Проблема в том что dagger не может инжектит data класс в repo, так как вы не прописали inject метод в AppComponent."

Comment: Если вы хотите инжектит data в repo а не передать через конструктор. Тогда вам надо 
1. Создать объект repo
2. Инжектит data в repo
3. Сделать так чтобы  dagger инжектил в класс usecase, repo тот который вы создали 1,2 этапах. Для этого repo надо сделать singleton

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не получается это на практике реализовать.
1. Создать объект Repo - т.е. в компоненте создаю `Repo getRepo();` и в активности `Repo repo = appComponent.getRepo()?` 
2. Инжектить data в репо. У меня указана аннотация `@Inject` в классе Repo у объекта Data,  верно? 
3. В UseCase так же указана аннотация `@Inject` у объекта Repo

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Inject на конструкторе, а не на поле

```
public class UseCase {
    
    Repo repo;

    @Inject
    public UseCase(Repo repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
    public void getText() {
        repo.repoText();
    }
}
```

Repo Класс:

```
public class Repo {
    Data data;

    @Inject
    public Repo(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void repoText(){
        data.getDataText();
    }
}
```

Data класс:

```
public class Data {
  
    @Inject
    public Data() {}

    public void getDataText(){
        System.out.println("ДАТА ТЕКСТ");
    }
}
```

Компонент:

```
@Component
public interface AppComponent {
    UseCase getUseCase();
}

AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.create();
    UseCase useCase = appComponent.getUseCase();
    useCase.getText();
```